# How to extract json value from given arrays

Tags: json

I have rows of return json from the plugin - pannellum (360 plugin). And I need to extract some values out of the glossary.

**JSON**

```
"hs2": {
  "title": "Toilet",
  "hfov": "110",
  "pitch": "-3",
  "yaw": "130",
  "type": "equirectangular",
  "panorama": "\/photos\/The-Peaks-Residence-Toilet-5a58b8ed2cb23.jpg",
  "hotSpots": [{
        "id": "33",
        "sid": "c8d9a346d2ce26c1be59d4f04938a9ce",//I need this
        "pitch": "-8.3325218",
        "yaw": "151.990469",
        "type": "scene",
        "text": "Door Way",
        "sceneId": "hs1"//I need this
      },
```

There're several set like this from the response. And there're some fields like `sid` and `sceneId` that I need. Please find the [sample here](https://pannellum.org/documentation/examples/hot-spots/) for a complete code.

To be honest, I don't know where to start. All I can think about is
 `console.log(hotSpots.sid)`
But it's not working. So, please help me out.

PS.I have fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ajsLdp5b/1/

Answer (score 0):

hotSpots contains an Array.
So it is

```
hotSpots[0].sid
```

That means

```
hs2.hotSpots[0].sid
```

as far as I can see it

Comment: I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: hotSpots is not defined`

Comment: You could have a look at you object first. This will show you all possible Keys in you object:    for (var prop in obj) {  console.log(prop); }

Comment: For all found Keys you can call: console.log(obj.key);

Comment: Hope that helps, see you tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, create an object/model that matches the data you want to extract, then push your values in it. In my example, I just get the sid in a Sid list.

```
let hotSpotSidList = []
hs2.hotspots.forEach((spot) => { 
   hotSpotSidList.push(spot.sid);
});
```

Comment: I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: hs2 is not defined`

Comment: Your json response is not well formatted, indeed it should start as an object { "hs2" ...

Comment: It is not a json object, in the doc I can see there's an API so that you can pass data and params through URL. Have you tried it ? 

In your example you just initialize your plugin, but don't create a class variable you can parse. Here is a closer example to what you want : https://pannellum.org/documentation/examples/custom-hot-spots/
Try viewer.getScene() or other function on your element

Comment: Yes, I've tried but the problem is how can I send the url without knowing the `sid`. So this is why I have to know the sid for the target page. :(

Comment: Don't get your needs, where the data come from ? Is it static or dynamic ?

Comment: I think you are mixing your job, but you should first get your json data, parse it normally and populate a table object you can use in your hotspots instead if a constant value